# Nutch not fetching any URL

Tags: hadoop, solr, nutch

I'm running Nutch 2 on a Hadoop cluster (2 nodes). I run the crawl command as

```
bin/crawl urls/seed.txt TestCrawl http://10.130.231.16:8983/solr/nutch 2
```

The screen shows that 765 URLs have been injected after filtering. The stats show that nothing has been fetched.

```
14/05/27 01:33:44 INFO crawl.WebTableReader: Statistics for WebTable: 
14/05/27 01:33:44 INFO crawl.WebTableReader: jobs:  {db_stats-job_201405261214_0047=     {jobID=job_201405261214_0047, jobName=db_stats, counters={File Input Format Counters =  {BYTES_READ=0}, Job Counters ={TOTAL_LAUNCHED_REDUCES=1, SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=10102,   FALLOW_SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0, FALLOW_SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=0, TOTAL_LAUNCHED_MAPS=1,   SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=10187}, Map-Reduce Framework={MAP_OUTPUT_MATERIALIZED_BYTES=6,   MAP_INPUT_RECORDS=0, REDUCE_SHUFFLE_BYTES=6, SPILLED_RECORDS=0, MAP_OUTPUT_BYTES=0,   COMMITTED_HEAP_BYTES=231735296, CPU_MILLISECONDS=2570, SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=1017,   COMBINE_INPUT_RECORDS=0, REDUCE_INPUT_RECORDS=0, REDUCE_INPUT_GROUPS=0, COMBINE_OUTPUT_RECORDS=0, PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES=313917440, REDUCE_OUTPUT_RECORDS=0, VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES=2243407872, MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS=0}, FileSystemCounters={FILE_BYTES_READ=6, HDFS_BYTES_READ=1017, FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=156962, HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=86}, File Output Format Counters ={BYTES_WRITTEN=86}}}}
14/05/27 01:33:44 INFO crawl.WebTableReader: TOTAL urls:    0
```

Why is this happening? My Regex-filter and Domain-filter are set to allow all domains (I'm trying to do whole web crawling).